# find multiple files that contains a specific word in unix and linux

Tags: linux, unix

Say i have list of files contain the word 'contain' in the same directory  and i want to find those files at one command . I have tried with grep command to find out like

```
   grep 'contain' file name
```

I tried  following command also.

```
    locate  'contain' 
    find 'contain'
    grep 'contain' file name
```

Currently i am not able to find any thing . Kindly help as its very important to find the files in a one command . Currently i am not able to find any thing . Kindly help as its very important to find the files in a one command . Currently i am not able to find any thing . Kindly help as its very important to find the files in a one command .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is within the question.

```
cd to the directory.
grep –l  ‘contain’ *
```

Hope it helps .

Comment: Thanks man . It showed me all the files that contains the word 'contain'. Thanks for help

Comment: I would suggest grep -r 'contain' . , since this will also search sub directory for any files contains the keyword.

Comment: thanks man, thanks for help